# Is it possible to compare all values from one (array) to one (case) only?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

```
var Array1 = ["hi", "hello"];
var Array2 = ["bye", "goodbye"];

var test = "hi";

switch (test) {
    case Array1:
        //code
        break:

    case Array2:
        //code
        break:

    default:
        //code
}
```

Comment: Greetings, welcome to StackOverflow.  I would recommend you review [ask].  For the question as posted, it is not clear what you are seeking.  Happy coding!

Comment: we'll need more context what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: What you've posted is not possible, you need to check the values using functions like `some`, `find`, `includes`, etc.

Comment: No, `switch` does not do that. Use `if (Array1.includes(test)) { … } else if (Array2.includes(test)) { … }`

Comment: I'm trying to make the (case Array1 :) compare all the values of Array1, without the need to create a case for each array index

Answer (score 1):

If you're not opposed to using a library, http://underscorejs.org/ has an intersection method, which can simplify this:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

var target = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'banana'];
var fruit2 = [ 'apple', 'orange', 'mango'];
var fruit3 = [ 'mango', 'lemon', 'pineapple'];
var fruit4 = [ 'orange', 'lemon', 'grapes'];

console.log(_.intersection(target, fruit2)); //returns [apple, orange]
console.log(_.intersection(target, fruit3)); //returns []
console.log(_.intersection(target, fruit4)); //returns [orange]
```

The intersection function will return a new array with the items that it matched and if not matches it returns empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to accomplish this:

```js
var Array1 = ["hi", "hello"];
var Array2 = ["bye", "goodbye"];

var test = "hi";

if (Array1.includes(test)) {
    console.log("in array1")
}

else if (Array2.includes(test)) {
    console.log("in array2")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to compare all values from one (array) to one (case) only?

No, your approach is comparing `"hi" === ["hi", "hello"]` and not what you're thinking about comparing every object within those arrays.

You need to use functions like `some`, `find`, `includes`, Etc.

*For example:*

```
if (array1.includes('hi')) {
    // Do stuff
} else if (array2.includes('hi')) {
    // Do stuff
} else {
    // Do default stuff
}
```